# Calculate Nyquist Frequency of signal from a data set

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, frequency, nyquist

I have a data set containing x (time) and y (concentration). Is it possible to calculate nyquist frequency from this ?

From the below time series the y values are being generated by solving a system of ODE's.

The time period of cycle is 24hrs (1440 min)

```
time=[0:0.05:1440]; %time in minutes
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given an evenly sampled signal sampled at a rate `R` samples per seconds, the [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) can be obtained as half the sampling rate or `R/2`.

In your specific case, you have 1 sample every 0.05 minute, so the sampling rate is 20 samples per minutes, or ~0.333 sample per seconds (i.e. ~0.333Hz). The Nyquist frequency is thus ~0.167Hz.

Comment: Thank you. So the Nyquist frequency only depends on the sampling rate ?

Comment: @SleuthEye: Do you have an email address where I could email you off list. This is not spam. Mine is markleeds2 at gmail.com. Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds if you need clarification on an existing answer, I usually reply to such requests when I receive the @ notification. Otherwise, if you have other questions that are on topic why not post them as such?

Comment: @SleuthEye. Would prefer to send  latex document to you. Thanks for all you do on this list. It's pretty amazing.: